# How to make a div scroll with respect to a textarea height?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, responsive-design, textarea

I am trying to make a mini code editor for my Angular project. Here I have a `textarea` and adjacent to it is a `div` showing the line numbers. Please refer to the below picture for the view:

[image: editor]

As you can see after line 23 the `div` has gone down below the footer whereas the `textarea` is not resized (Textarea resizing is set to false in CSS). What I want is to behave like a normal code editor like if the `textarea` gets overflow then accordingly the div will scroll (but no scrollbar in line number div).

Is is possible to make it? Please help me out.

Refer this [url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w2rwjt?file=src/app/app.component.html) for live example.

Comment: is your footer a `display: block` or `position: absolute` or something?

Comment: @Techuila it's ```display: block```

Comment: All I can see is an empty bordered box in the link that you've provided

Comment: in the url given above ?

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample code to stick the footer at the bottom, and make the main div scrollable.

I've based it on the given url you provided. I just added a sample footer for you to have an idea on how to implement it.

**app.component.html**

```html
<div class="app-container">
  <div class="coding_container" style="flex-grow: 1;">
    <div>
      <div class="code-row">
        <div class="column-1">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let i of lineNumber">{{i}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column-2">
          <textarea [(ngModel)]="code" (input)="countLine()"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="min-height: 80px; background-color: blue;">
    FOOTER
  </div>
</div>
```

**styles.css**

```css
html, body, my-app {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

my-app {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.app-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}

.coding_container {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And lastly add `overflow-y: hidden` to your textarea

**app.components.css**

```css
textarea {
  resize: none !important;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: consolas;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  overflow-y: hidden;  // add this
  /* border: none; */
}
```

[image]